# How to eliminate redundancy when creating variants of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So currently I have my values like this for example:

```
        values = {
            'order_line_id': order.id,
            'product_id': product.id,
        }
```

But conditionally, I want to add an extra line while keeping the previous values, for example:

```
if field == 0:
     # Add a new line to values
```

So my question is how can I update my values without having to copy the values that I currently have and just add a new line to it.

I don't want it to look like this, but I'm not certain if there is another way:

```
if field == 0:
         values = {
            'order_line_id': order.id,
            'product_id': product.id,
            'new_line': line.id
        }
else:
        values = {
            'order_line_id': order.id,
            'product_id': product.id,
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the base case, then conditionally add the extra field:

```
values = {
        'order_line_id': order.id,
        'product_id': product.id,
}
if field == 0:
    values['new_line'] = line.id
```

Comment: Or, in case you want to add multiple key-value pairs, `values.update(key1=val1, key2=val2, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

What you have right now is a **dictionary**.
A dictionary works by mapping a **key** to a **value**: `'key' : value`

```
values = {
    'order_line_id': order.id,
    'product_id': product.id,
}
```

So in this instance: 
Your first key is `'order_line_id'` and it's value is `order.id`
Your second key is `'product_id'` and it's value is `product.id`.
To add a new key and value, you simply define the key and set it equal to it's value:

```
if field == 0 :
    values['new_key'] = newValue
```

So now if field does equal 0:

```
print(values)
>>> {'order_line_id': order.id, 'product_id': product.id, 'new_key' : newValue}
```

If it doesn't:

```
print(values)
>>>{'order_line_id': order.id, 'product_id': product.id}
```